# eval is not a function

Tags: javascript, syntax, eval

It might interest somebody and save few hours, a nasty bundling problem, eval is from one file and function is from second file.

```
eval('console.log(0)')
(function(x){console.log(x)})(1)
```

will result with: Uncaught TypeError: eval(...) is not a function

and this is the fix

```
eval('console.log(0)');
(function(x){console.log(x)})(1)
```

missing semicolon, I've read few times that semicolon in JS optional most of the time.

any comments why eval is not a function in this context?

Comment: Though semi colon insertion is optional. It is good to understand that when would JS engine actually insert a semi colon. Reading throug this answer might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi

Comment: the lesson from here is always put semicolon between files in bundle :)

Comment: This can happen when you pass some `undefined` variable into `eval`. In my case I didn't imported some global variable in Postman:
`eval(globals.some_function)();`

Answer (score 10):

The JS runtime is not perfect at guessing where semi-colons should go.

When it sees this:

```
eval('console.log(0)')
(function(x){console.log(x)})(1)
```

It incorrectly assumes that the result of the immediately invoked function expression is part of the `eval` line (a potential parameter to be passed to the potential function that the `eval` evaluates to).

Here's an example of when that would work:

```js
eval("(function(message){ alert(message); })")
("Hi there!");
```

But, in your case, `eval` is not evaluating to a function, so trying to pass an argument to it fails, thus your error message.

But, it actually has less to do with `eval()`, in particular. This can pop up anytime a semi-colon is omitted just prior to an IIFE or any expression starting with a `(`.

Adding the semi-colon, allows the runtime to know that the IIFE is separate.

The rule is that you must insert semi colons on any line that is followed by a `(` (as this is how an expression can begin) in order to keep them separate . But, the better rule is to not rely on automatic semi-colon insertion at all and always put them in yourself.

Comment: this was my guess but finding this was quite a nightmare, because this kind of code was not written by hand, it was concat of many third party libs

Comment: @maciejW Oh, and by the way, the use of `eval()` is highly discouraged in the first place. It can lead to cross-site scripting attacks, is slow and runs in a modified scope-chain. There is almost always a way to refactor the code to not need `eval()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the few situations in which Javascript's [semicolon insertion](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/08/26/javascript-semi-colon-insertion/) will trip you up.

This code:

```
eval('console.log(0)')
(function(x){console.log(x)})(1)
```

Is equivalent to this code:

```
eval('console.log(0)')(function(x){console.log(x)})(1)
```

In other words, Javascript thinks that the expression `eval('console.log(0)')` evaluations to a function which you are trying to call with the parameter `(function(x){console.log(x)})`. That is obviously not what you intended, so you need semicolons at the end of your lines.